# Atribuir um valor à minha td dentro de uma table com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Não consigo atribuir um valor à minha td dentro de uma tabela, ela contém `id` dinâmico como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover" id="tabelaDependentes">
    <caption>Lista de Dependentes</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>CPF</th>
            <th>Tipo Dependente</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="cursor: pointer" data-depedente-id="30">
            <td id="depedente-cpf-30">2323</td>
            <td id="depedente-tipo-30">teste</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="cursor: pointer" data-depedente-id="31">
            <td id="depedente-cpf-31">09298618417</td>
            <td id="depedente-tipo-31">teste</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="cursor: pointer" data-depedente-id="32">
           <td id="depedente-cpf-32">jose2</td>
            <td id="depedente-tipo-32">teste</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="cursor: pointer" data-depedente-id="33">
            <td id="depedente-cpf-33">123</td>
            <td id="depedente-tipo-33">teste</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Porém o código JS não funciona:

```
$("#depedente-cpf-31").html('teste');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Minha resposta ficou mais como uma "demonstração" das outras funções
>   que podem ser utilizadas, o erro realmente deve ser a falta da
>   referência ao jQuery ou é tentado acessar o elemento antes do mesmo
>   ser criado, como foi citado na resposta do @Randrade

- Usa o [jQuery.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) para adicionar conteúdo no fim do elemento
- E o [jQuery.prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) para adicionar conteúdo no começo do elemento.
- O [jQuery.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) substitui todo o conteúdo do elemento pelo novo.

```js
$("#div1").append(" <b>Adicionado usando append()</b>");
$("#div2").prepend("<b>Adicionado usando prepend()</b> ");
$("#div3").html(" <b>Adiciondo usando html()</b> ");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">Texto original</div>
<div id="div2">Texto original</div>
<div id="div3">Texto original</div>
```

Comment: o problema que ele nem encontra esse id , dá undefined

Comment: Fiz um teste com teu HTML e funcionou. Editei a resposta agora.

Comment: A maneira que você está fazendo deveria funcionar também. Você adicionou a referencia do jQuery?

Answer (score 4):

A forma que está fazendo está correta. Verifique se você está referenciando o jQuery corretamente.

Outro possível problema é você está chamando a função antes da tabela estar formada. Se for isso, basta alterar o seu script de posição, ou adicionar o [$(document).read()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) à sua função.

```js
$("#depedente-cpf-31").html('Olha, funcionou');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover" id="tabelaDependentes">
  <caption>Lista de Dependentes</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>CPF</th>
      <th>Tipo Dependente</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="cursor: pointer" data-depedente-id="30">
      <td id="depedente-cpf-30">2323</td>
      <td id="depedente-tipo-30">teste</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="cursor: pointer" data-depedente-id="31">
      <td id="depedente-cpf-31">09298618417</td>
      <td id="depedente-tipo-31">teste</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="cursor: pointer" data-depedente-id="32">
      <td id="depedente-cpf-32">jose2</td>
      <td id="depedente-tipo-32">teste</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="cursor: pointer" data-depedente-id="33">
      <td id="depedente-cpf-33">123</td>
      <td id="depedente-tipo-33">teste</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

> Por fim, caso não funcione, abra o console do browser (F12) e poste o erro que está aparecendo.